# MySQL files conflicts with other package

Tags: mysql, yum

> Error: mysql55-libs conflicts with mysql-libs-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64
>   conflicts with mysql-libs

while trying to do install `mysql55-libs`.

Could u please help me on this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).